# Masking non-ASCII strings with Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, mask, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to mask string with javascript regex. But there is a problem with non-ascii characters. How do you think I can solve this problem?

This is my code:

```js
var name = "Üsüaüü Bxbdüxüqzx Aqwexü"
var regex = /(?<![\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Nd}_])(\p{L})(\p{L}*)\b/ug
console.log(name.replace(regex, (_, first, middle, last) => `${first}${'*'.repeat(middle.length)}`))
```

Expected output:

```
Ü***** B********* A*****
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: You can omit the word boundary `var regex = /(?<![\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Nd}_])(\p{L})(\p{L}*)/ug`

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace this line

```
var regex = /(?<![\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Nd}_])(\p{L})(\p{L}*)\b/ug
```

Into

```
var regex = /(?<![\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Nd}_])(\p{L})(\p{L}*)/ug
```

I hope you got your solution